# Is there any way to restore EXT4 partition

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, formatting, ext4

Is there any way to restore ext4 partition after formatting the entire hard disk then making two partitions of NTFS

Answer (score 2):

[Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) supports ext4. The [example](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) uses ntfs but you should be able to apply it to any file system.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are against you on this one. The new partitions more than likely overwrote the previous partition tables.

However if you're just looking to recover files from the previous partitions and haven't copied any data onto the new partitions, you should still be easily able to retrieve most of your files, then repartition it back and copy the recovered data onto the partitions.

If you need further assistance, let me know and I can detail the steps for you.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to.

I once accidentally reformatted an NTFS disk with an (empty) ext3 partition. Software that can recover data from such a situation isn't common, but it is out there.

The main thing that is important is whether or not you wrote any files to the disk after reformatting it. Once you start writing files, you are potentially destroying any latent data.

Answer (score -1):

Download the Program IM Magic Partition it will Fix Repair and even Swap Partitions on any HDD/SSD without losing any Data! I have used it just about a Dozen times the past 2 years and No Problems