# Recover Files from an unknown-type partition

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, ntfs, ext4

Information:

- windows 7
- ubuntu 16.04
- ubuntu LiveCD

I lost a partition during windows installation so i used Testdisk on ubuntu to recover that partition and i edited some partitions there,added new ones

then i went back to my windows(7) and started formatting the partitions i made before ,but apparently,my ubuntu home partition type was changed from EXT4 to NTFS by testdisk and i accidently formatted it using windows quick format.now i want to recover the home partition.

1.should i use ntfs partition recover tools like "ntfsundelete" or such? or should i look for a way to recover my partition based on ext4 partition?

2.whats the best way to recover the data using linux?there are some ways [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) but i dont know about the differences between them.

Comment: Are there specific files you wish to recover, or do you just need to recreate a home partition for your Ubuntu install?

Comment: @music2myear i want to recover everything(as much as possible),not specific file type or files.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/246788/is-there-any-way-to-restore-ext4-partition?rq=1 Testdisk supports EXT4, apparently. Also, recovering data and then restoring the partition is likely to be a two-step process. It is UNLIKELY you'll be able to recover the data in the partition and use it as the Home partition right away. You'll need to identify and recover the data to a different partition, then recreate the partition and configure it, then restore the necessary data to it.